# Is it to possible create a simple chat facility using XMPP with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, chat, instant-messaging

I would like to create a web IM chat system using Google App Engine using XMPP possibly.

It would allow users of a social network to talk with each other.
Is this possible using GAE?

I haven't used GAE before. Does anybody know of any good examples/code which I could look into to get started?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634510/is-it-possible-to-create-an-im-chatting-service-on-the-cloud/1634541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your communication is between users who are interacting with your site directly, there's no need to use XMPP, or benefit from it - just write your IM system into the site directly. XMPP support is designed for interaction with external IM services.

Alternately, you could embed the [Google Talk gadget](http://googletalk.blogspot.com/2007/03/google-talk-gadget.html) in your site, but that will require users to sign in to their Google accounts to use it.

Comment: ok, the reason I asked about XMPP was because I needed real-time chatting software. So does GAE support COMET or something similar?

Comment: comet is not possible you could fake it using an external api? http://www.brightyellowcow.com/blog/Comet-AJAX-push-using-PHP-or-Google-App-Engine.html

Comment: The approach there is called 'long polling', and isn't supported in App Engine.

Comment: @chris: No, not currently. Embedding the Google Talk gadget may be practical; using other external services is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. I would start with reading http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html in order to get started.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was looking at that document, but couldn't figure out if it was possible for two people using GAE to communicate with each other (without using an external XMPP server). Do you know if that is possible?